# Highchart/Highstock Data sampling

Tags: javascript, highcharts, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on asp.net MVC 5 
I want to sample the data in the following way

1. Take the difference of two points (next point - previous point)
2. Plot them in between the time range

I will explain the point number **2** shortly, please see the bellow image for visual understanding

[image]

The red line is the difference between two point (as written in point **1**)

The chart is for **energy_kwh**

For point **2** take the following example

For example, there are **3** points having values **5**, **7**, **9** and they are plotted with respective time i.e. **3** time range likely **2 PM** **3 PM** and **4 PM**, but if i take there differences like **7 - 5 = 2** and **9 - 7 = 2** then i have **2** values/points, but the time is still **3**, i want to plot the new points in between the time range like from **2 pm to 3pm** the point is **2** so it will display in between the time.

I know how to take the difference between two points but i am unable to draw them on chart as i don't know how to manage the time range

Bellow is my controller code

```
SqlCommand Device_Id_command = new SqlCommand("Select Device_ID, Energy_kWh,Power_kW,Voltage_Phase_1,Data_Datetime,Voltage_Phase_2,Voltage_Phase_3,Current_Phase_1,Current_Phase_2,Current_Phase_3 from [ADS_Device_Data] where Device_Serial_Number=@serial_number AND Data_Datetime between'" + time.ToString(format) + "'AND'" + time2.ToString(format) + "'", con);
                Device_Id_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@serial_number", serial_number);

                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = Device_Id_command.ExecuteReader();
                //SqlDataReader reader_events = event_command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    energy_kwh.Add(Convert.ToDouble(reader["Energy_kWh"]));
                    power_kw.Add(Convert.ToDouble(reader["Power_kW"]));
                    voltage_1.Add(Convert.ToDouble(reader["Voltage_Phase_1"]));
                    voltage_2.Add(Convert.ToDouble(reader["Voltage_Phase_2"]));
                    voltage_3.Add(Convert.ToDouble(reader["Voltage_Phase_3"]));
                    current_1.Add(Convert.ToDouble(reader["Current_Phase_1"]));
                    current_2.Add(Convert.ToDouble(reader["Current_Phase_2"]));
                    current_3.Add(Convert.ToDouble(reader["Current_Phase_3"]));
                    Meter_datetime.Add(sample_con.ConvertToUnixTimestamp(Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Data_Datetime"])));
                    device_id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Device_ID"]);
                }
                con.Close();
```

After that i have passed them in my ViewData

```
ViewData["energy_kwh"] = energy_kwh;
```

Bellow is my razor syntax

```
    var myArrayX_kwh = [];
    var myArrayY_kwh = [];
    var arry_kwh = [];

    @foreach (var st in ViewData["energy_kwh"] as List<double?>)
    {
        @:myArrayY_kwh.push(@st);
    }

     for (var i = 0; i < myArrayX_kwh.length; i++) 
     {
        arry_kwh.push({ x: myArrayX_kwh[i], y: myArrayY_kwh[i], });
     }

    var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container1',
            type: 'column',
            zoomType: 'xy',
            panning: true,
            panKey: 'shift',

            resetZoomButton: {
                position: {

                    x: -10,
                    y: 350,

                },

                relativeTo: 'chart'
            }
        },
        scrollbar:{
            enabled: true
        },
        navigator: {
            enabled: true,

            height: 30,

        },

        rangeSelector: {


            buttonTheme: { // styles for the buttons
                fill: 'none',
                stroke: 'none',
                'stroke-width': 0,
                r: 8,
                style: {
                    color: '#039',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                },
                states: {
                    hover: {
                    },
                    select: {
                        fill: '#039',
                        style: {
                            color: 'white'
                        }
                    }

                }
            },
            enabled: true,
            inputBoxWidth: 160,
            inputStyle: {
                color: '#039',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            labelStyle: {
                color: 'black',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            buttons: [{
                type: 'minute',
                count: 60 * 6,
                text: '6h'
            }, {
                type: 'day',
                count: 1,
                text: '1d'
            }, {
                type: 'day',
                count: 7,
                text: '7d'
            },
            {
                type: 'day',
                count: 14,
                text: '2w'
            },
            {
                type: 'day',
                count: 21,
                text: '3w'

            },
            {
                type: 'month',
                count: 1,
                text: '1m'
            },
            {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }]

        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                turboThreshold: 50000
            }

        },
        title: {
            text: 'Energy vs Date & Time',
            style: {

                fontWeight: 'bold',

            }
        },
        xAxis: {

            type: 'datetime',
            //min: 0,
            //max: 100000

        },

        yAxis:
        {
            scrollbar: {
                enabled: true,
                showFull: false

            },
            alternateGridColor: '#FDFFD5',
            title: {
                text: 'Energy (kWh)',
                style: {
                    fontSize: '12px',

                }
            }


        },

        series:
        [
            {
                name: 'Energy kWh',
                color: 'green',
                data: arry_kwh,
            }

        ],
    });
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: It sounds like you just need to also calculate the difference between the x values of the two points, at the same time that you're calculating the difference between the y values, and plot the 'difference' series just like you are the main series.

Comment: Yes i want to do this

Comment: Ok, so, you said you know how to get the difference between the two points - you just have to do the same exact thing with the x values. The dates are just integers. Where is your code for getting the difference for the `y` values?

Comment: I have followed  [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/8fjyLhy1/5/) but didn't get the result

Comment: also i have done  'arry_kwh.push({ x: myArrayX_kwh[i], y: myArrayY_kwh[i+1] - myArrayY_kwh[i], });' in my loop

Comment: So, if you just add the same piece to your `x` that you're using for your `y`, you should be all set:  `.push({ x: (myArrayX_kwh[i+1] - myArrayX_kwh[i]), y: (myArrayY_kwh[i+1] - myArrayY_kwh[i]), });`  If not, set up a fiddle with some example data

Comment: i have already provided a  JsFiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, right, so the calculation is just slightly more complex than in my comment, as I wasn't accounting for needing the x values to build on the current base value.

What you really need for your x value on the difference array is, the current x value, plus half of the difference between the current and next x values.

So this:

```
arry_kwh_diff[i] = {x: arry_kwh[i].x, y:arry_kwh[i+1].y - arry_kwh[i].y};
```

Becomes:

```
arry_kwh_diff[i] = {
  x: arry_kwh[i].x + ((arry_kwh[i+1].x - arry_kwh[i].x) / 2), 
  y: (arry_kwh[i+1].y - arry_kwh[i].y)
};
```

Updated fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/8fjyLhy1/6/

Comment: hats off to you, you just saved me :)

Comment: Why `arry_kwh[i].x + ((arry_kwh[i+1].x - arry_kwh[i].x) / 2)` should it be just `(arry_kwh[i+1].x - arry_kwh[i].x)` ?

Comment: @Faisal no, because we're not looking for the difference between the two time stamps, we're looking for the previous timestamp plus half the difference between the current and next time stamp. With the data set in the example, you will return an x value of 1,000 for each data point, when what you're looking for is 1588169185668, 1588169186668, etc. so that we can plot the data between the existing datetime x values.